# Determine if a place with type of natural_feature is an island

Tags: google-places-api

For example `Majorca, Balearic Islands, Spain` (place_id: `ChIJKcEGZna4lxIRwOzSAv-b67c`)

has the following types:

```
natural_feature,
establishment,
geocode
```

Is it safe to assume that those types combined will always mean that the place is an island, or is there some other way to tell if the "place" is an island?

Answer (score 0):

`natural_feature` indicates a prominent natural feature, not limited to islands, so it is **not** safe to assume that it is an island. For example: *Pelješac, Croatia* also has types: `establishment, natural_feature` and it is a peninsula, not an island.